# Android lifecycle methods apparently called out of order when Activity started by context.startActivity(intent)

Tags: android

I'm launching an Activity from another (an AlarmReceiver) with Intent flags FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.  If the target activity is already running and visible, this should (and does) clear and restart it.  However, in the target activity, the lifecycle methods are called consistently in this order:

```
onPause();
onCreate();
onStart();
onResume();
onStop(); 
onDestroy();
```

Yes, onDestroy() is the last one called, after onResume(), but the Activity is left running.

Once I worked out what was happening, I can code round it.

But is this right?  What am I missing?

Comment: My guess is that you are seeing lifecycle events from two distinct activity instances, the one being cleared and the one being created.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.  I hadn't thought of that.  In my example, the lifecycle methods alter a couple of static variables and class members shared by all instances, so the order matters!  Anyway, havng identified the issue I could work round it OK.  I just couldn't understand why.  Thanks again!